# Error msb3191 solution

Tags: build, message

I develop DLL project in **native C++** under **VS2013 Professional**, **Win7 64b Enterprise**.

The project has 4 configurations as one can see from the snippet below.

At some stage, I added to the project's properties the post-build step as follows:

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)$(TargetName).ini" "$(TargetDir)*.*"
```

The project was successfully built and the .ini file was copied as expected. But following error were reported:

```
Error 1  error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "D:\MES\MULTICHANNEL\MULTITHREAD\IOM\IOM.ini D:\MES\MULTICHANNEL\MULTITHREAD\x64\Release". The given path's format is not supported.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets
1228 5  IOM
Error 2  error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "D:\MES\MULTICHANNEL\MULTITHREAD\IOM\IOM.ini D:\MES\MULTICHANNEL\MULTITHREAD\Release". The given path's format is not supported.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets
1228 5  IOM
Error 3  error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "D:\MES\MULTICHANNEL\MULTITHREAD\IOM\IOM.ini D:\MES\MULTICHANNEL\MULTITHREAD\x64\Debug". The given path's format is not supported.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets
1228 5  IOM
Error 4  error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "D:\MES\MULTICHANNEL\MULTITHREAD\IOM\IOM.ini D:\MES\MULTICHANNEL\MULTITHREAD\Debug". The given path's format is not supported.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets
1228 5  IOM
```

What's going here?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The right solution was to define in the post-build step as follows:

```
copy $(ProjectDir)$(TargetName).ini $(TargetDir)*.*
```

that is, to omit all the quotation marks `"`.